# How to count month wise days on given date in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a date and I need to count the days in current and previuos months of same year.

Suppose I have a date like 23-April-2017

What I need:

```
Jan-2017 - 31

Feb-2017 - 28 

March-2017 - 31

April-2017 - 30
```

I am not able to create a query to get these counts.

Comment: Your expected output is inconsistent. Do you want year in there or not?

Comment: Doesnt matter. But days calculation should be based on the year user have passed. Anyway updated the question. thanks.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

This code do what you want, just set variable @d to the needed date:

```
set @d=date("2017-02-17");
set @d1=date(concat(year(@d),"-",month(@d),"-01"));
set @d2=ADDDATE(@d1,32);
set @d2=date(concat(year(@d2),"-",month(@d2),"-01"));
select if(month(@d1)=12,31,dayofyear(@d2) - dayofyear(@d1));
```

**Edited version** for all month till the selected date:
First I need a table for the months:

```
create table months(id INT);
insert into months (id) values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12);
```

With this statement and the correct date inserted I get the desired last month dates:

```
set @d=date("2017-07-17");
select
    concat(
        DATE_FORMAT(date(concat(year(@d),'-',id,'-1')),'%M - %Y - '),
        dayofmonth(last_day(date(concat(year(@d),"-",id,"-01")))))
from
    months where id between 1 and month(@d);
```

This delivers:

```
January - 2017 - 31
February - 2017 - 28
March - 2017 - 31
April - 2017 - 30
May - 2017 - 31
June - 2017 - 30
July - 2017 - 31
```

Comment: You are right, I added a new version for all month till selected date.